# Failed to find mclmcrrt*.dll with Matlab Runtime

Tags: java, matlab, dll, runtime

I've created a Matlab's function that I want to call from a Java App. Since I don't have matlab installed in this machine I use Matlab Runtine (version 8.5, 32 bits).

When I execute the code, I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the required library mclmcrrt8_5.dll on java.library.path.
This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MCR. Its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or the current path configuration.
The MCR version that this component is trying to use is: 8.5.

```
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.get(MCRConfiguration.java:259)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:265)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getProxyLibraryDir(MCRConfiguration.java:270)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:71)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:81)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getMCRRoot(MCRConfiguration.java:86)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ModuleDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:60)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getModuleDir(MCRConfiguration.java:65)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1503)
at BCI.BCIMCRFactory.newInstance(BCIMCRFactory.java:60)
at BCI.BCIMCRFactory.newInstance(BCIMCRFactory.java:71)
at BCI.Class1.<init>(Class1.java:104)
at bci.pruebaEEG.main(pruebaEEG.java:24)
```

I've included to my PATH environment's variable the dll's path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Matlab\Matklab Runtime\v85\runtime\win32

Matlab's version used to create the previous function was R2015a (32bits) and to compile the Java Package, jdk 1.7 (they're supposed to be compatible).

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to find the solution to my dll's problem. So, if someone else is also getting continuously this "Failed to find the required library mclmcrrt8_5.dll on java.library.path." error and has already followed this [steps](http://es.mathworks.com/help/compiler/deploying-to-end-users.html), please check if your jre version matches with the 32/64 bits version of the matlab compiler (MCR)

I was running my Java application from Eclipse and fool of me I didn't realize I was using (x64) jre7 instead of (x86). I just had to download the correct one and add it to the JRE System library. Now everything runs perfectly.